# How to implement cookie authentication | SvelteKit & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, cookies, sveltekit

The question stands as-is - how to implement cookie authentication in a SvelteKit & MongoDB app? Meaning how to properly use hooks, endpoints, establish a DB connection and show it on a boilerplate-ish project.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## After SvelteKit Project Initialisation

### #1 Install additional dependencies

```
npm install config cookie uuid string-hash mongodb
```

- I prefer **config** over **vite**'s .env variables due to all the leaks and problems regarding it
- **cookie** is used to properly set cookies
- **uuid** is used to generate complex cookie IDs
- **string-hash** is a simple yet secure hashing for passwords stored in your DB
- **mongodb** is used to establish a connection to your DB

### #2 Set up `config`

In root, create a folder called *config*. Inside it, create a file called *default.json*.

#### `config/default.json`

```
{
    "mongoURI": "<yourMongoURI>",
    "mongoDB": "<yourDatabaseName>"
}
```

### #3 Set up base DB connection code

Create `lib` folder in `src`. Inside it, create `db.js` file.

#### `src/lib/db.js`

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import config from 'config';

export const MONGODB_URI = config.get('mongoURI');
export const MONGODB_DB = config.get('mongoDB');

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
    throw new Error('Please define the mongoURI property inside config/default.json');
}

if (!MONGODB_DB) {
    throw new Error('Please define the mongoDB property inside config/default.json');
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongo;

if (!cached) {
    cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

export const connectToDatabase = async () => {
    if (cached.conn) {
        return cached.conn;
    }

    if (!cached.promise) {
        const opts = {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        };

        cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((client) => {
            return {
                client,
                db: client.db(MONGODB_DB)
            };
        });
    }
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
    return cached.conn;
}
```

The code is taken from **next.js** implementation of MongoDB connection establishment and modified to use **config** instead of **.env**.

### #4 Create `hooks.js` file inside `src`

#### `src/hooks.js`

```
import * as cookie from 'cookie';
import { connectToDatabase } from '$lib/db';

// Sets context in endpoints
// Try console logging context in your endpoints' HTTP methods to understand the structure
export const handle = async ({ request, resolve }) => {
    // Connecting to DB
    // All database code can only run inside async functions as it uses await
    const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
    const db = dbConnection.db;

    // Getting cookies from request headers - all requests have cookies on them
    const cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.cookie || '');
    request.locals.user = cookies;

    // If there are no cookies, the user is not authenticated
    if (!cookies.session_id) {
        request.locals.user.authenticated = false;
    }

    // Searching DB for the user with the right cookie
    // All database code can only run inside async functions as it uses await
    const userSession = await db.collection('cookies').findOne({ cookieId: cookies.session_id });

    // If there is that user, authenticate him and pass his email to context
    if (userSession) {
        request.locals.user.authenticated = true;
        request.locals.user.email = userSession.email;
    } else {
        request.locals.user.authenticated = false;
    }

    const response = await resolve(request);

    return {
        ...response,
        headers: {
            ...response.headers
            // You can add custom headers here
            // 'x-custom-header': 'potato'
        }
    };
};

// Sets session on client-side
// try console logging session in routes' load({ session }) functions
export const getSession = async (request) => {
    // Pass cookie with authenticated & email properties to session
    return request.locals.user
        ? {
                user: {
                    authenticated: true,
                    email: request.locals.user.email
                }
          }
        : {};
};
```

**Hooks** authenticate the user based on cookies and pass the desired variables (in this example it is the user's email etc.) to context & session.

### #5 Create `register.js` & `login.js` Endpoints inside `auth` folder

#### `src/routes/auth/register.js`

```
import stringHash from 'string-hash';
import * as cookie from 'cookie';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { connectToDatabase } from '$lib/db';

export const post = async ({ body }) => {
    // Connecting to DB
    // All database code can only run inside async functions as it uses await
    const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
    const db = dbConnection.db;

    // Is there a user with such an email?
    const user = await db.collection('testUsers').findOne({ email: body.email });

    // If there is, either send status 409 Conflict and inform the user that their email is already taken
    // or send status 202 or 204 and tell them to double-check on their credentials and try again - it is considered more secure
    if (user) {
        return {
            status: 409,
            body: {
                message: 'User with that email already exists'
            }
        };
    }

    // Add user to DB
    // All database code can only run inside async functions as it uses await
    await db.collection('testUsers').insertOne({
        name: body.name,
        email: body.email,
        password: stringHash(body.password)
    });

    // Add cookie with user's email to DB
    // All database code can only run inside async functions as it uses await
    const cookieId = uuidv4();
    await db.collection('cookies').insertOne({
        cookieId,
        email: body.email
    });

    // Set cookie
    // If you want cookies to be passed alongside user when they redirect to another website using a link, change sameSite to 'lax'
    // If you don't want cookies to be valid everywhere in your app, modify the path property accordingly
    const headers = {
        'Set-Cookie': cookie.serialize('session_id', cookieId, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            path: '/'
        })
    };

    return {
        status: 200,
        headers,
        body: {
            message: 'Success'
        }
    };
};
```

If you want to take it a step further, don't forget to create **Schemas** with **Mongoose**!

#### `src/routes/auth/login.js`

```
import stringHash from 'string-hash';
import * as cookie from 'cookie';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { connectToDatabase } from '$lib/db';

export const post = async ({ body }) => {
    const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
    const db = dbConnection.db;

    const user = await db.collection('testUsers').findOne({ email: body.email });

    if (!user) {
        return {
            status: 401,
            body: {
                message: 'Incorrect email or password'
            }
        };
    }

    if (user.password !== stringHash(body.password)) {
        return {
            status: 401,
            body: {
                message: 'Unauthorized'
            }
        };
    }

    const cookieId = uuidv4();

    // Look for existing email to avoid duplicate entries
    const duplicateUser = await db.collection('cookies').findOne({ email: body.email });

    // If there is user with cookie, update the cookie, otherwise create a new DB entry
    if (duplicateUser) {
        await db.collection('cookies').updateOne({ email: body.email }, { $set: { cookieId } });
    } else {
        await db.collection('cookies').insertOne({
            cookieId,
            email: body.email
        });
    }

    // Set cookie
    const headers = {
        'Set-Cookie': cookie.serialize('session_id', cookieId, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            path: '/'
        })
    };

    return {
        status: 200,
        headers,
        body: {
            message: 'Success'
        }
    };
};
```

### #6 Create `Register.svelte` and `Login.svelte` components

#### `src/lib/Register.svelte`

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    // Dispatcher for future usage in /index.svelte
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    // Variables bound to respective inputs via bind:value
    let email;
    let password;
    let name;
    let error;

    const register = async () => {
        // Reset error from previous failed attempts
        error = undefined;

        try {
            // POST method to src/routes/auth/register.js endpoint
            const res = await fetch('/auth/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email,
                    password,
                    name
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });

            if (res.ok) {
                dispatch('success');
            } else {
                error = 'An error occured';
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            error = 'An error occured';
        }
    };
</script>

<h1>Register</h1>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" bind:value={name} />
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" bind:value={email} />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" bind:value={password} />
{#if error}
    <p>{error}</p>
{/if}
<button on:click={register}>Register</button>
```

#### `src/lib/Login.svelte`

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    // Dispatcher for future usage in /index.svelte
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    // Variables bound to respective inputs via bind:value
    let email;
    let password;
    let error;

    const login = async () => {
        // Reset error from previous failed attempts
        error = undefined;

        // POST method to src/routes/auth/login.js endpoint
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/auth/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email,
                    password
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });

            if (res.ok) {
                dispatch('success');
            } else {
                error = 'An error occured';
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            error = 'An error occured';
        }
    };
</script>

<h1>Login</h1>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" bind:value={email} />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" bind:value={password} />
{#if error}
    <p>{error}</p>
{/if}
<button on:click={login}>Login</button>
```

### #7 Update `src/routes/index.svelte`

#### `src/routes/index.svelte`

```
<script>
    import Login from '$lib/Login.svelte';
    import Register from '$lib/Register.svelte';
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    // Redirection to /profile
    function redirectToProfile() {
        goto('/profile');
    }
</script>

<main>
    <h1>Auth with cookies</h1>

    <!-- on:success listens for dispatched 'success' events -->
    <Login on:success={redirectToProfile} />
    <Register on:success={redirectToProfile} />
</main>
```

### #8 Create `index.svelte` inside `profile` folder

#### `src/routes/profile/index.svelte`

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ session }) {
        if (!session.user.authenticated) {
            return {
                status: 302,
                redirect: '/auth/unauthorized'
            };
        }

        return {
            props: {
                email: session.user.email
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let email;
    let name;

    onMount(async () => {
        const res = await fetch('/user');
        const user = await res.json();
        name = user.name;
    });
</script>

<h1>Profile</h1>
<p>Hello {name} you are logged in with the email {email}</p>
```

Pay attention to **session** we set up in `hooks.js`. `console.log()` it to understand its structure better. I won't be implementing `/auth/unauthorized` route, so mind that.

### #9 Create `index.js` endpoint inside `user` folder

#### `src/routes/user/index.js`

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '$lib/db';

export const get = async (context) => {
    // Connecting to DB
    // All database code can only run inside async functions as it uses await
    const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
    const db = dbConnection.db;

    // Checking for auth coming from hooks' handle({ request, resolve })
    if (!context.locals.user.authenticated) {
        return {
            status: 401,
            body: {
                message: 'Unauthorized'
            }
        };
    }

    const user = await db.collection('testUsers').findOne({ email: context.locals.user.email });

    if (!user) {
        return {
            status: 404,
            body: {
                message: 'User not found'
            }
        };
    }

    // Find a proper way in findOne(), I've run out of gas ;)
    delete user.password;

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: user
    };
};
```

### Final thoughts

There are almost none tutorials regarding SvelteKit and I'll surely find this guide useful in my future projects. If you find a bug or see an improvement, feel free to let me know so I can make this guide better ;)

### Big thanks to Brayden Girard for a precedent for this guide!

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGl66MHcjMDJyIPZkuKULSQ

#### Happy coding!

Comment: For all that work, wouldn't a public github repo be really helpful to all ?

Comment: [Public repo done. Click here...](https://github.com/zipzit/Sveltekit_Cookie_Auth)  Note you will have to add your own Mongodb Atlas login info...

Comment: @Nikolas Thank you for the answer. Is it secure to pass `authorization info` through `locals.user.authenticated`? Can't hackers set it to `true` and have access to private pages?